# SOS Mobile SDK Header Framework Error

Tags: mobile, ios, chat, video

I'm trying to setup an environment to use SOSService in my iOS app (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.service_sdk_ios.meta/service_sdk_ios/ios_sos_quick_start.htm), after set the Podfile with this following code :

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/goinstant/pods-specs-public'

target 'Clickforce' do
    pod 'ServiceSDK'
end
```

and run my project, I'm receiving this error from X-Code

```
/Clickforce/Pods/ServiceSDK/Frameworks/ServiceSOS.framework/Headers/SOSNetworkReporter.h:26:9: 

Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'ServiceSOS.SOSNetworkReporter'
```

This error appears with these two header files : ServiceSOS.h, SOSCameraBasedViewController.h

I'm not able to run my code, after check on another sites, I enabled the configuration to allow non modular includes in framework modules but still doesn't work,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same error and only way was able to get around this was by manually importing the files myself .

> Add the relevant frameworks to the Embedded Binaries section of the General tab for your target app. Be sure to select Copy items if needed when embedding.
>
> Once you’ve embedded the frameworks, you’ll automatically see them appear in the Linked Frameworks and Libraries section as well.

[image]